# Looping Quiz, Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

Alrighty so, I'm supposed to make a quiz that consists of 5 questions with 4 possible answers. The user then will answer the questions via keyboard input. At the end if they have 5 out of 5 the program should outprint, "excellent" at 4 it should output "Very Good" and at 3 or less is should outprint "Time to brush up on your knowledge of global warming" along with a link to the site with information used to create the questions. included in the coding must be, "Do-While", and "Switch" Statements. I think its almost there but I keep getting errors and I'm really having a hard time figuring out what to do next! Help a lady out?

**Edit** Here are my received errors: 
***"Multiple markers at this line
- chosenAnswer1 cannot be resolved
- chosenAnswer1 cannot be resolved to a 
 variable
- answer1string cannot be resolved to a 
 variable"*****

(My code is below)

```
import java.io.* ;
public class globalwarming {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputStreamReader keyInput = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ;
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(keyInput) ;

        try {
               System.out.println("1.   Carbon Dioxide (CO2)_____________;");
               System.out.println("A.   Is colorless, odorless, non-toxic, and non-combustible.");
               System.out.println("B.   Is produced when Carbon sources are burned (i.e. oil, coal, gas, wood…)");
               System.out.println("C.   Atmospheric concentration has increased by over 34% since 1960.");
               System.out.println("D.   All of the above");
               String chosenAnswer1 = read.readLine();
               int answer1 = 4;
               String answer1string = "" + answer1;
               String Question1answers;
               switch (answer1) {
                   case 1:  Question1answers = "A.  Is colorless, odorless, non-toxic, and non-combustible.";
                            break;
                   case 2:  Question1answers = "B.  Is produced when Carbon sources are burned (i.e. oil, coal, gas, wood…)";
                            break;
                   case 3:  Question1answers = "C.  Atmospheric concentration has increased by over 34% since 1960.";
                            break;
                   case 4:  Question1answers = "D.  All of the above";
                            break;
                   default: Question1answers = "No response selected";
                            break;
               } 
               System.out.println("2.   Greenhouse gases are;  ");
               System.out.println("A.   A myth created by popular media.");
               System.out.println("B.   Keep heat close to earth sustaining life, however is rapidly increasing heat levels, which is detrimental to the environment.");
               System.out.println("C.   Green colored gases that poison and kill plant life.");
               System.out.println("D.   Nothing to be concerned about, continue buying and consuming products that release CO2 emissions… Nothing to see here.");
               String chosenAnswer2 = read.readLine();
               int answer2 = 2;
               String answer2string = "" + answer2;
               String Question2answers;
               switch (answer2) {
                   case 1:  Question2answers = "A.  A myth created by popular media.";
                            break;
                   case 2:  Question2answers = "B.  Keep heat close to earth sustaining life, however is rapidly increasing heat levels, which is detrimental to the environment.";
                            break;
                   case 3:  Question2answers = "C.  Green colored gases that poison and kill plant life.";
                            break;
                   case 4:  Question2answers = "D.  Nothing to be concerned about, continue buying and consuming products that release CO2 emissions… Nothing to see here.";
                            break;
                   default: Question2answers = "No response selected";
                            break;
               } 
               System.out.println("3.   Smart Cars help combat global warming by,");
               System.out.println("A.   Reducing CO2 emissions slowing the rapid warming of the planets atmosphere.");
               System.out.println("B.   Consuming more energy thereby eliminating oil supplies.");
               System.out.println("C.   Require fewer resources to manufacture.");
               System.out.println("D.   None of the above.");
               String chosenAnswer3 = read.readLine();
               int answer3 = 1;
               String answer3string = "" + answer3;
               String Question3answers;
               switch (answer3) {
                   case 1:  Question3answers = "A.  Reducing CO2 emissions slowing the rapid warming of the planets atmosphere.";
                            break;
                   case 2:  Question3answers = "B.  Consuming more energy thereby eliminating oil supplies.";
                            break;
                   case 3:  Question3answers = "C.  Require fewer resources to manufacture.";
                            break;
                   case 4:  Question3answers = "D.  None of the above.";
                            break;
                   default: Question3answers = "No response selected";
                            break;
               } 
               System.out.println("4.   There is more carbon dioxide in the air today than;");
               System.out.println("A.   There ever has been before.");
               System.out.println("B.   Than at any other time in the last 800,000 years.");
               System.out.println("C.   Than there will be in 20 years.");
               System.out.println("D.   Both A and B.");
               String chosenAnswer4 = read.readLine();
               int answer4 = 2;
               String answer4string = "" + answer4;
               String Question4answers;
               switch (answer4) {
                   case 1:  Question4answers = "A.  There ever has been before.";
                            break;
                   case 2:  Question4answers = "B.  Than at any other time in the last 800,000 years.";
                            break;
                   case 3:  Question4answers = "C.  Than there will be in 20 years.";
                            break;
                   case 4:  Question4answers = "D.  Both A and B.";
                            break;
                   default: Question4answers = "No response selected";
                            break;
               } 
               System.out.println("5.   In the last century sea levels have risen how many inches?");
               System.out.println("A.   5 Inches");
               System.out.println("B.   0 Inches");
               System.out.println("C.   7 Inches");
               System.out.println("D.   22 Inches");
               String chosenAnswer5 = read.readLine();
               int answer5 = 3;
               String answer5string = "" + answer5;
               String Question5answers;
               switch (answer5) {
                   case 1:  Question5answers = "A.  5 Inches";
                            break;
                   case 2:  Question5answers = "B.  0 Inches";
                            break;
                   case 3:  Question5answers = "C.  7 Inches";
                            break;
                   case 4:  Question5answers = "D.  22 Inches";
                            break;
                   default: Question5answers = "No response selected";
                            break;
               }
        }
        int i = 5;
        String strI = "" + i;
        int count = 0;
        do {
            if (chosenAnswer1 == answer1string) {
                count++;
            }
            if (chosenAnswer2 == answer2) {
                count++;
            }
            if (chosenAnswer3 == answer3) {
                count++;
            }
            if (chosenAnswer4 == answer4) {
                count++;
            }
            if (chosenAnswer5 == answer5) {
                count++;
            }
        } while (count <= 5);
            if (count == 5) {
                System.out.println("Excellent!");
            } else if (count == 4) {
                System.out.println("Very good!");
            } else if (count > 3) {
                System.out.println("Time to brush up on your knowledge of global warming.");
                System.out.println("http://www.dosomething.org/actnow/tipsandtools/11-facts-about-global-warming");
            }
        /*
        System.out.println(Question1answers);
        System.out.println(Question2answers);
        System.out.println(Question3answers);
        System.out.println(Question4answers);
        System.out.println(Question5answers);
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to learn to use a debugger and use it.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Please add the errors you get to the question, this helps answering alot.

Comment: Why have you used case statements to check the value of a variable that you have just set?  This isn't really what they're for.  Maybe you should just replace all of the case statements with simple checks of whatever the user actually typed.

Comment: @Hollie, is better you learn about switch command. But you're going right, keep learning.

Comment: I added the received errors thx!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html
Cases does not mean order in your menu, they are like "IF the given variable equals THIS case value"

```
switch (STRING) {
case STRING_A: do something.. break;
case STRING_B:  do something.. break;
}
switch (INTEGER) {
case 1: do something.. break;
case 2:  do something.. break;
}
```

This variable is defined in a try context. It cannot be used outside the try.

```
String chosenAnswer1 = read.readLine();
```

You will have to do something like:

```
 String chosenAnswer1 = null;
        try {
        ...
        chosenAnswer1 = read.readLine();
```

The same for all other chosenAnswers and answer1strings

Your try is missing the catch/finally, otherwise why would you use a try?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

`read.readLine();` These lines need to be wrapped by try catch OR the method should allow the exception throw.

Strings are immutable, therefore stringA==stringB does not evaluate if the strings are the same, it will evaluate if the two strings are the same Object....

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "hello";
//a==b is false.
//a.equals(b) is true
String a = "hello";
String b = a;
//a==b is true.
//a.equals(b) is true
```

Answer (score 1):

your use of `==` for strings incorrect. Strings should be checked for equality using `.equals()` For example, this line, and all others below it:

```
if (chosenAnswer1 == answer1string) {
```

This should be

```
if (chosenAnswer1.equals(answer1string)) {
```